# Fragment shader 16bit texture access

Tags: opengl-es

I'm using the "OES_texture_half_float" extension but have been unable to read the  16 bit values from a png texture exported through photoshop

```
gl.texImage2D  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.HALF_FLOAT, texture.image)
```

values taken from `teximage2d(uSampler, vTextureCoord)` do not yield correct results any idea as to what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Um, I'm pretty sure PNG's 16-bit pixel format is fixed-point (unsigned normalized), not floating-point. If it were floating-point, there'd never have been a need for specialized formats like OpenEXR. You will get pure garbage trying to transfer pixel data that is unsigned normalized into a half-float in GLES, it does not support data conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  It seems the better way for me to go about obtaining info from a data table into texture is using the OES_texture_float and binding to a texture created with FloatArray32 . Anything I should be wary of?

Comment: How are you generating the input data for the texture from the PNG data? You can't feed 16-bit fixed-point directly into OpenGL ES - the application has to convert it into a OpenGL format before uploading it. Using float32 will have exactly the same problem as float16 - the original data isn't in that format.

Comment: values are generated out of another 3d application then parsed through javascript which then creates a map containing the floating point values.